# is there a way to define variables in the python library pywhatkit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to build an app using Tkinter and Pywhatkit , the functionality is that you enter the phone no.,message and time ( in minutes,seconds).I did the front end but the back end is a little complicated , here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pywhatkit
root = tk.Tk()

def Function():
    n=Entry1.get()
    m=Entry2.get()
    l=Entry3.get()
    i=Entry4.get()
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91n","m",l,i)
    

Label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Mscheduler",bg='#99e6ff',font="Verdana 34")
Label1.grid(columnspan=1)

Label2= tk.Label(root,text="Enter phone no.",bg="#c2f0c2",font="verdana 22")
Label2.grid(row=2 , column=0)

Entry1=tk.Entry(root,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 22")
Entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)

Label3= tk.Label(root,text="Enter message.",bg="#c2f0c2",font="verdana 22")
Label3.grid(row=3 , column=0)

Entry2=tk.Entry(root,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 22")
Entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)

Label4= tk.Label(root,text="Enter time.",bg="#c2f0c2",font="verdana 22")
Label4.grid(row=4 , column=0)

Entry3=tk.Entry(root,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 22")
Entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)

Entry4=tk.Entry(root,bg="#ffe6b3",font="verdana 22")
Entry4.grid(row=4, column=2)

Button1=tk.Button(root, text="send", bg="#d1d1e0", font="verdana 16", command=Function)
Button1.grid(row=5, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In simple words, your error is at `pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91n","m",l,i)` change that to `pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(f"+91{n}",m,l,i)`

Comment: @CoolCloud - That wont work. The `l` and `i` variables or the `get()` that created them need to be wrapped in `int()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the `pywhatkit` docs and looked at the function you are trying to use. It wants a phone number in string format, a message in string format, an hour in int format, and a minute in int format.

I renamed all of your `Entry` widgets to 'phone', 'message', 'hour' and 'minute', because that's what they are. I then changed your 'message' `Entry` to a `Text` widget. I was thinking that the 15 or so characters that you were allowing for a message, isn't enough to say anything, at all. I then renamed your `Function` function to `send`, because that's what it does.

Finally, I set the arguments in the `sendwhatmsg` call to a phone number in string format, a message in string format, an hour in int format, and a minute in int format, because that's exactly what the docs said to do.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pywhatkit


root = tk.Tk()
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)


def send():
    #print(f'+91{phone.get()}', message.get('1.0', 'end-1c'), int(hour.get()), int(minute.get()))
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(f'+91{phone.get()}', message.get('1.0', 'end-1c'), int(hour.get()), int(minute.get()))
    
#title
tk.Label(root, text="Mscheduler", bg='#99e6ff', font="Verdana 34").grid(columnspan=3, sticky='w')

#phone
tk.Label(root,text="Phone: ", bg="#c2f0c2", font="verdana 22").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
phone = tk.Entry(root, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 22", width=10)
phone.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w', columnspan=2)

#message
tk.Label(root,text="Message: ", bg="#c2f0c2", font="verdana 22").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nw')
message=tk.Text(root, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 22", height=4, width=32)
message.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w', columnspan=2)

#time
tk.Label(root,text="Time HH:MM", bg="#c2f0c2", font="verdana 22").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
#hour
hour=tk.Entry(root, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 22", width=2)
hour.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')
#minute
minute=tk.Entry(root, bg="#ffe6b3", font="verdana 22", width=2)
minute.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w')

#send button
tk.Button(root, text="send", bg="#d1d1e0", font="verdana 16", command=send).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='e')


root.mainloop()
```